# ¿Por qué los markdown están "frenando" mi pagina?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, r-markdown, laravel-10

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel 10, el cuál se trata de una "venta" de componentes para pc, el problema es al momento de cargar un producto en específico y mostrar sus características; para mostrarlas uso archivo .md y una librería llamada "Parsedown", para darles estilos uso el plugin "@tailwindcss/typography". Desde mi virutal-host y desde XAMPP carga todo bien, pero al cargarlo con "php artisan serve" de alguna manera los markdown impiden que cargue la especificación del producto y bloquea la página, sé que son los markdown porque cuando abro la descripción de un producto que no usa markdowns abre de manera correcta. Aquí el controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\productos;

class ProductoController extends Controller
{
    public function show($categoriaSlug, $productoSlug){
        // Buscar la categoría por su slug
        $categoria = Categoria::where('slug', $categoriaSlug)->firstOrFail();

        // Buscar el producto en la categoría por su slug
        $producto = $categoria->productos()->where('slug', $productoSlug)->firstOrFail();

        return view('productos.producto',compact('categoria', 'producto'));
    }
}
```

Acá la vista:

```
{{-- Declaracion e importacion componente principal --}}
@extends('layouts.productos')

{{-- Declaracion complemtento etiqueta title del Header, la variable $categoria se pasa mediante el controlador y se detecta con el switch --}}
@section('title', "$producto->modelo - $categoria->nombre_categoria")


{{-- Declaracion contenido principal de la pagina web --}}
@section('content')
  {{-- Declaracion y envio de clases personalidas a la etiqueta body presente en el componente principal--}}
  @section('body_class','flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-100')
  {{-- Envio de clases personalizadas a la etiqueta main, la cual se encuentra en el componente principal--}}
  @section('main_class','container mt-3 mb-10 text-justify mx-auto flex-grow mx-2')

  <div class="contenedor mx-8 my-3 text-sm hover:underline">
    <a href="{{route('index')}}" class="hover:text-blue-600 hover:underline inline-flex items-center gap-1">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-share fa-flip-horizontal"></i> <p>Volver</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 my-6 gap-4 py-3 bg-white px-3 mx-8 rounded-lg"> 
      <div class="flex flex-col text-center font-medium col-span-2">
        <img class="w-full sm:w-2/4 md:w-3/4 mx-auto sm:mx-20" src="{{asset('storage/' . $producto->imagen)}}" alt="">
      </div>
      <aside class="flex flex-col p-2 sm:p-3 desc-producto gap-y-2 text-start ms-3 sm:ms-0 ">
        <p class="text-gray-400 text-xs">Descripción del producto</p>
        <ul class="flex flex-col gap-y-2 sm:gap-y-4">
            <li class="text-xl sm:text-2xl hover:underline"><p class="font-bold">{{$producto->modelo}}</p></li>
            <li class="text-lg sm:text-xl">$ {{number_format($producto->precio, 0, '.', '.')}}</li>
        </ul>
        @if (file_exists(public_path('storage/' . $producto->descripcion_1)))
        <div class="especificaciones prose prose-sm my-2 hover:prose-h3:underline">
          {!! Parsedown::instance()->text(file_get_contents(asset('storage/' . $producto->descripcion_1))) !!}
        </div>            
        @else
        <div>{{$producto->descripcion_1}}</div>
        @endif
      </aside>
      {{-- La segunda descripción es opcional, la primera no --}}
      @if ($producto->descripcion_2)
        @if (file_exists(public_path('storage/' . $producto->descripcion_2)))
        <div class="col-span-2 text-center prose prose-lg mx-auto hidden sm:flex sm:flex-col gap-4 hover:prose-h4:underline">
          {!! Parsedown::instance()->text(file_get_contents(asset('storage/' . $producto->descripcion_2))) !!}
        </div>
        @else
        <div class="hidden sm:flex mx-auto">{{$producto->descripcion_2}}</div>
        @endif
      @endif

  </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Ves algo en la consola del navegador o en los logs de PHP?

Comment: ¡Hola! Cuando doy clic no aparece nada en el registro de las consolas, luego de que pasan unos 60 segundos aproximadamente me da este log en la vista "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

Comment: Para ello debo cambiar el "FILESYSTEM_DISK" del .env?

Comment: No. No funciona, creo que se debe a que los tengo dentro de la carpeta "public/storage/espefic_productos/prueba.md", ¿puede ser?

Comment: Sí, lo cree con php artisan storage:link. Y el path que me da es este "storage/especif_productos/prueba.md"

Comment: Sí. Mira, esto devuelve en la vista "C:\xampp\htdocs\PcGlobal\public\storage/especif_productos/prueba.md"

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo logré solucionar, ahora manejo la información de los markdown desde el controlador y los mando en una variable como arreglo: Acá dejo el controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\productos;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Parsedown;

class ProductoController extends Controller
{
    public function show($categoriaSlug, $productoSlug){
        // Buscar la categoría por su slug
        $categoria = Categoria::where('slug', $categoriaSlug)->firstOrFail();

        // Buscar el producto en la categoría por su slug
        $producto = $categoria->productos()->where('slug', $productoSlug)->firstOrFail();

        if (file_exists(public_path('storage/'. $producto->descripcion_1))){
            $contenidoMd = File::get(public_path('storage/'.$producto->descripcion_1));
            $parsedown = new Parsedown();
            $descripcion_1 = $parsedown->text($contenidoMd);
        }else{
            $descripcion_1 = $producto->descripcion_1;
        }

        // La segunda descripción es opcional, la primera no

        if($producto->descripcion_2){
            if(file_exists(public_path('storage/'. $producto->descripcion_2))){
                $contenidoMd = File::get(public_path('storage/'.$producto->descripcion_2));
                $parsedown = new Parsedown();
                $descripcion_2 = $parsedown->text($contenidoMd);
            }else{
                $descripcion_2 = $producto->descripcion_2;
            }
        }else{
            $descripcion_2 = null;
        }

        $descripciones = compact('descripcion_1', 'descripcion_2');


        return view('productos.producto',compact('categoria', 'producto','descripciones'));
    }
}
```